# Static text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am looking for a way to make a template value for an input.

I have this input:

[image: input]

I want "st. No. bl. en. fl. ap." to be static values that cannot be changed in the input and the users to be able to write only between (on red) them.
I need to get the whole string ("st. 7th Ave No.86 bl.34 ...") after that so "make several inputs" is not an idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get the whole string from several inputs ? You know you can concatenate strings ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret it is a requirement.

Comment: Did you look at jquery masked inputs? http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: It is a requirement that you can not concatenate strings?

Comment: Yes, the requirement is to be in one input so i can get the whole string.

Comment: Your best bet is a masked input plugin like vyx proposed, I prefer [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin).

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: "Yes, the requirement is to be in one input so i can get the whole string." You can get the whole string from several inputs, who decided you could have only one input ?

Comment: Use a regex with json to switch focus

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom inputs to make it looks like what you want and then concatenate them in your code .
As an example :http://jsfiddle.net/3h9zmxk3/3/

```
<div class="input-container">
 <span class="fix-text">St.</span><input type="text" class="my-input">
 <span class="fix-text">No.</span><input type="text" class="my-input">
 <span class="fix-text">bl.</span><input type="text" class="my-input">
 <span class="fix-text">en.</span><input type="text" class="my-input">
 <span class="fix-text">fl.</span><input type="text" class="my-input">
 <span class="fix-text">ap.</span><input type="text" class="my-input">
</div>
```